# How can i read the month names from a jQuery UI Datapicker language file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm using jQuery datepicker in a web app and i allow end users to pick their language. For datepicker i'm loading the locale files(translation files) and everything works fine.

My question is :

How can i read & use  the month names, day names etc from a jQuery datapicker language file. For example  the datepicker-de.js file look like this:

```
/* German initialisation for the jQuery UI date picker plugin. */
/* Written by Milian Wolff (mail@milianw.de). */
(function( factory ) {
    if ( typeof define === "function" && define.amd ) {

        // AMD. Register as an anonymous module.
        define([ "../datepicker" ], factory );
    } else {

        // Browser globals
        factory( jQuery.datepicker );
    }
}(function( datepicker ) {

datepicker.regional['de'] = {
    closeText: 'SchlieÃŸen',
    prevText: '&#x3C;ZurÃ¼ck',
    nextText: 'Vor&#x3E;',
    currentText: 'Heute',
    monthNames: ['Januar','Februar','MÃ¤rz','April','Mai','Juni',
    'Juli','August','September','Oktober','November','Dezember'],
    monthNamesShort: ['Jan','Feb','MÃ¤r','Apr','Mai','Jun',
    'Jul','Aug','Sep','Okt','Nov','Dez'],
    dayNames: ['Sonntag','Montag','Dienstag','Mittwoch','Donnerstag','Freitag','Samstag'],
    dayNamesShort: ['So','Mo','Di','Mi','Do','Fr','Sa'],
    dayNamesMin: ['So','Mo','Di','Mi','Do','Fr','Sa'],
    weekHeader: 'KW',
    dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',
    firstDay: 1,
    isRTL: false,
    showMonthAfterYear: false,
    yearSuffix: ''};
datepicker.setDefaults(datepicker.regional['de']);

return datepicker.regional['de'];

}));
```

I want to read the monthNames and daynames and use it in another script. Having a new object/file for all datepicker languages is not an option,

Thank you

Comment: hint: `new Date(2019, 0, 1).toLocaleString('de', {month:'long'})` and `new Date(2019, 2, 1).toLocaleString('de', {month:'short'})`

Comment: Thx, but i need to the whole array not only the current Month. For ex : ['So','Mo','Di','Mi','Do','Fr','Sa']

Comment: So, that doesn't give you a starting point? ... `var longmonths = Array.from({length:12}, (_, m) => new Date(2019, m, 1).toLocaleString('de', {month:'long'}))` for example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use date toLocaleString method

example below are all in `de` locale as per question

long month names

```js
const longmonths = Array.from({length:12}, (_, m) => 
    new Date(2019, m, 1).toLocaleString('de', {month:'long'})
);

console.log(longmonths);
```

short months

```js
const shortmonths = Array.from({length:12}, (_, m) => 
    new Date(2019, m, 1).toLocaleString('de', {month:'short'})
);

console.log(shortmonths);
```

Note: For day of week, I picked July 2019, because July 1 2019 is a Monday

long day of week (Sunday -> Saturday)

```js
const longdow = Array.from({length:7}, (_,d) => 
    new Date(2019, 6, d).toLocaleString('de', {weekday:'long'})
);

console.log(longdow);
```

short day of week (Sunday -> Saturday)

```js
const shortdow = Array.from({length:7}, (_,d) => 
    new Date(2019, 6, d).toLocaleString('de', {weekday:'short'})
);

console.log(shortdow);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker();   
}); 

alert($.datepicker.formatDate("MM", "datepicker"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Get Array of DayNames and MonthNames

```
var monthName = $.datepicker.regional["de"].monthNames;
var dayName = $.datepicker.regional["de"].dayNames;
```

Get monthName and dayname according to date.

```
var date = new Date();
var monthName = $.datepicker.regional["de"].monthNames[date.getMonth()];
var dayName = $.datepicker.regional["de"].dayNames[date.getDay()]
```

Comment: seems logical, but I have `undefined`